# how to print value regular interval of time?

Tags: javascript

I am using closure in java script to print 1-10 value after each 2 sec.In other words first print 1 then wait for two second then print 2 .I used closure but nothing work .

Here is my code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, 2000);
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```js
function loopWithDelay(callback, delay, max, min) {
  var i = min || 0;
  if (i <= max) {
    var id = setInterval(function() {
      callback(i);
      if (++i > max) clearInterval(id);
    }, delay);
  }
}

loopWithDelay(function(i) { console.log(i) }, 2000, 10);
```

Or use a recursive `setTimeout`:

```js
function loopWithDelay(callback, delay, max, min) {
  var i = min || 0;
  if (i <= max) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(i);
      loopWithDelay(callback, delay, max, ++i);
    }, delay);
  }
}

loopWithDelay(function(i) { console.log(i) }, 2000, 10);
```

Comment: I want to write about it but you are first :)

Comment: I downvoted this answer as I consider the use of `setInerval` a very bad practice and should be avoided. Read here some reasons: https://zetafleet.com/blog/2010/04/why-i-consider-setinterval-to-be-harmful.html

Comment: @Cristy `setInterval` isn't harmful. It's just asynchronous. Many people don't understand what that means.

Comment: @4castle The problem is not that it's `asynchronous`, but that using `setTimeout` you can do whatever `setInterval` does, only better and safer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), you can make a function that call itself using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```js
  (function myFunc(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(index);
      if (index < 10) myFunc(++index);
    }, 2000)
  })(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet.

```js
var i=1;
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(i<11){
    console.log(i);  
    i++;
  }else{
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for it and use recursive `setTimeout` calls.

```
function printDelay(current, last, delay) {
   console.log(current);
   if(++current <= last) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         print(current, last, delay);
      }, delay);
   }
}

printDelay(1, 10, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that hasn't been presented here, and one that will probably get closest to executing "on-time," would be to just set all your timeouts at the same time, each having the desired delay before execution. If you have a smaller, fixed number, this should be fine.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i + 1); // Add 1 to i for display purposes
  }, (i + 1) * 2000); // Execute every 2 seconds starting at 2 seconds
}
```

This is essentially the same as:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, i * 2000); // Execute every 2 seconds starting at 2 seconds
}
```

To start immediately instead of after 2 seconds, the first timeout value just has to come at 0 instead of 2000 (milliseconds).